# Gathering Data from UI elements inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I am building a form using a `UITableView` with many different types of `UITableViewCell`s These cells may have a `UITextView`, `UISwitch`, `UISlider`, `UITextField`, etc.

I need to have gathered all the user's input into a `Dictionary` so I can send the user input back to the server.

Would the best way of gathering the data is by setting the delegates of all the UI elements to the Controller?

So for `UITextView`, in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

sampleTextView.delegate = self
sampleTextView.tag = [tagNumber]
```

And then getting the text and adding/updating the dictionary in `- textViewDidEndEditing:`

Note - Also, the forms are built dynamically and can change.

Comment: You set the delegate for the elements to self to make your class respond to the event changes of those elements. That is a basic step to do. To get data from them , you don't have to set delegate, you could simply get the data from the element attributes.Your question is too broad, pls provide more details of what you are trying to do!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I am not sure what you mean by "get the data from the element attributes"? A user is basically filling out a form that is built using a `UITableView` and there are many different types of UI objects. I want to capture all the input data and store it. I am asking what is the best way to capture all that data so when the user presses "Submit", I can send all the information to the server.

Comment: @Alan, if the details entered are straightforward then local instance variables can store them and on SUBMIT a request can be formed with these variables in a format the server supports.

Answer (score 0):

in your UIViewController

```
var formInfo:NSMutableDictionary = [:]
```

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method set indexPath as tag

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      //... config cell

      cell.sampleTextView.delegate = self
      cell.sampleTextView.tag = indexPath.row

      //because you are use UITableView in dynamic mode textView will lost text in scrolling , 
      if formInfo.objectForKey(textview.tag) != nil {
           cell.sampleTextView.text = formInfo.objectForKey(textview.tag) as? String
      }

    }
```

and in your textView Delegate :

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

        formInfo.setObject(textView.text, forKey: textView.tag)

    }
```